# 1 Question, 2 Answers

Tags: probability-theory

Consider the following problem: In a bullet firing competition $A$ can hit $4$ out of $5$ bullet in target, similar chances of $B$ is $3$ out of $4$ and for $C$ is $2$ out of $3$.They fire simultaneously and exactly two out of them makes correct hit.What is the probability that $C$ has missed the target?
Let $X$: $A$ hits the target, $Y$: $B$ hits the target,$Z$: $C$ hits the target.
Solution $1$: The required probability is ${P(XYZ^c ) \over P(XYZ^c )+P(YZX^c )+P(ZXY^c ) }$=${{4 \over 5}{3 \over 4}{1 \over 3} \over {4 \over 5}{3 \over 4}{1 \over 3}+{3 \over 4}{2 \over 3}{1 \over 5}+{2 \over 3}{4 \over 5}{1 \over 4}}$=${6 \over 13}$.

Solution $2$: The required probability is $P(XYZ^c )={1 \over 5}$.

So, my question is which of the solution is correct, and why the other one is incorrect, that is what is the question that the other solution makes that answer$?$

Comment: The probability that only C misses given that two out of three hit, is the same at the probability that only C misses.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 is correct.  The conditional probability (of being given that exactly two of the three participants hits the target) puts you in a restricted sample space.  This is why you need to use the conditional probability formula of solution 1.

Comment: So what should be the question for the solution 2(to get solution 2 as the answer)?

Comment: The question for which 'solution 2' is the answer would be "what is the probability that A and B both hit the target and C misses the target?".

Comment: But, A and B both hit the target and C misses the target is same as exactly two of them hit the target and C missed the target.

Comment: Yes, but in the actual problem, you are given the additional information that exactly two of the three hit the target.  This additional information causes you to have a reduced sample space.  That is we're interested in ABC' occurring but only out of the possibilities ABC', AB'C, A'BC.  All the other possibilities are no longer relevant.